# Way to get the current URL (or Drive Folder ID) from within a G Suite Add-on for Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, gsuite-addons

Using a G Suite Add-on for Drive, I need to retrieve the ID of the current folder.  Drive add-ons only provide contextual event objects when an item is selected.  If I click a file, the event object includes the file ID, which I can then use to retrieve the parent ID.

However, if I don't physically select an existing file within a folder, it's considered non-contextual, and any action event object doesn't seem to contain enough info to obtain the folder ID.

G Suite Add-ons permit use of selected Google Apps Script services.  Is there a way to get the current URL, or another way to obtain the folder ID without having to select a file within it?

Comment: You're right, there is no way to get information on the current folder if no file is clicked. If you give more details on why you want to do that and what's the ultimate purpose, maybe a workaround could be found.

Comment: My business maintains a Drive folder for each client, and we would like to display customer details when inside the folder. I've considered requiring the user to select at least one file before displaying customer info, but after working with G Suite Add-ons for a week now, I'm running into more of these kinds of limitations. I'm likely headed back to Chrome extensions for this type of integration.

Comment: `I've considered requiring the user to select at least one file before displaying customer info`: I'd just go with this in your situation.